# Как перераспределить порядковый номер в перечне записей?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

**ИМЕЕТСЯ**
Таблица-справочник со следующими полями:
- id;
- порядковый номер записи (пример 1,2,3,..., n);
- наименование записи;

Справочник используется в базе данных.
Необходимо чтобы **"наименование записи"** имело определённую последовательность.
Последовательность обеспечивается по средствам сортировки поля **"порядковый номер записи"**.

**СИТУАЦИЯ**
Составлен справочник (исходный: вариант-0).
Справочник используется в других таблицах.
В процессе работы возникает необходимость **добавить запись** в середину списка и тем самым перераспределить порядковые номера, которые ниже **добавленной записи**.

**ВОПРОС.**
Как решить данную задачу?
Т.е. перенабивать новые порядковые номера вручную, думаю ненормально.
Или есть другой поход к данной ситуации?

Comment: `update "Таблица-справочник" set "порядковый номер записи"="порядковый номер записи"+1 where "порядковый номер записи">=123`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если справочник изменяется нечасто, то вставить новый элемент можно с помощью `UPDATE`

`UPDATE position = position+1 WHERE position>=:position`
`INSERT ... (position, ...) VALUES (:position, ...)`

Также может иметь смысл изменение интерфейса редактирования справочника,
вместо ввода позиции вручную, пользователю предлагается перемещать элементы.
Если вместо перемещения и вставки реализовать обмен позициями двух элементов - не придётся обновлять весь справочник на действие пользователя.

Answer (score 1):

Другой подход конечно же имеется. Почему бы порядковый номер не умножить на 100 или 1000 ?

100

200

300

400

И если потребуется добавить запись между ними проблем не возникнет.. до определенного момента ;-)

Либо воспользоваться timestamp полем в качестве сортировки. Но опять же.. придется ручками править, либо писать функцию чтобы запись была между нужными.

Comment: `до определенного момента ;-)` вот я и думаю... что до момента